# How to use makestyles in react to get correctly something like myclass.h1?

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I am trying to use useStyles in my React app. What I want to achieve is to get style for elements inside the className working. Could you please make a hint? My code is below. Thanks :]

In CSS, you would normally use something like

```
.myClass {
 color: red;
}

.myClass.h1 {
  color: blue
}

...
...

<div class="myClass">
  <span>this is red text</span>
  <h1>this is blue text</div>
</div>
```

my actual react code is something like:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({  
  myClass: {
    color: "red",
    h1: {
      color: "blue",
    }
  }
}

...
...

  const classes = useStyles();

return (
 <div className={classes.myClass}>  
       <span>this is red text</span>
        <h1>this is blue text</h1>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is

```
  myClass: {
    color: "blue",  
    "& > h1": {
      color: "red",
    },
  },
```